# Android Studio. Переход к строке вызова функции

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

никак не могу найти сию кнопочку... скажем, сработал брекпоинт какой-то часто вызываемой функции, как я могу перейти в строку вызова этой функции? то есть как я могу узнать откуда эта функция вызвалась? смотрел в горячих клавишах в справке Идеи, тоже не встретил...

Comment: В нижнем левом углу, при стандартной настройке, появляется стек вызовов для брейкпоитна. Пощелкайте по нему.

Comment: Вам нужно перейти к реализации метода по строке вызова этого метода или что?

Comment: мне нужно перейти к той строке, откуда была вызвана функция в данном брекпоинте. стек вызовов нашел, но при некотором количестве разных асинхронных потоков там помойка образовывается. либо я не совсем разобрался с этим окошком. спасибо, гляну еще раз